# A tensor product for dg-categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, tensor-products

For a finite group denote by $\mathbf{Ch}^G$ the dg-category of $G$-representations in chain complexes over a field.

Is there a tensor product $\otimes$ of dg-categories (similar to the Deligne tensor product for Abelian categories) such that for another finite group $H$
\begin{align} (*) \quad \quad \mathbf{Ch}^{G\times H} \cong \mathbf{Ch}^G \otimes \mathbf{Ch}^H \quad \quad ?\end{align}

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Yes, at least for presentable $dg$-categories.  The idea is to take $A \hat \otimes B$ to be the category of co-continuous functors from the naive tensor product $A \otimes B$  to $\rm Ch$.  This paper might have more info https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408337.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you explain why this tensor product will give me equivalences like (*)?